# Do you work or are you a student?

Tags: grammaticality, colloquial-language

If someone is asked the question below,

> Q: Do you work or are you a student?
>   A: Neither. I had a job couple of months ago, but I lost it because...

does this answer above sound correct?

Comment: That’s like asking “Are you married, or do you have a job instead?”

Comment: Nope. In fact these two options are relevant, especially when you can not know from his/her appearance.

Comment: @tchrist - In India, that question is too common. Here, it is taken that if you are a student, you couldn't be working and vice versa. Not that I agree with them.

Comment: What a strange question. I'm halfway through my Software Engineering degree and part of my study is to work for a year, on an industrial placement. I would say both here :^)

To be more on topic, the answer sounds as right as it could be, as strange/rude as the question sounds...

Comment: One could work and be a student. One could be unemployed and not be a student. One could be retired. One could be a housewife. For that matter, being a student might involve work, but that's probably just being contrary: we know what the questioner meant by "work". Of course real life is full of questions like this with debateable assumptions. "Are you a member of my political party or are you a racist?" etc

Comment: It is the question which some of IELTS examiners ask in Iran and most of them are from Australia or Italy.

Comment: I think a better way to ask this question would be "Do you have a full-time job, or are you a full-time student?" (In the U.S., a full-time job is usually 40 hours a week, and a full-time student takes at least 12 credit hours of coursework.) Many full-time students have part-time jobs, and many full-time workers are part-time students, but you don't find too many people who work full time while they are full-time students.

Comment: @tchrist In an IELTS speaking test, one would be asked "Do you work or study?". I am wonder if [that](https://band7success.com/do-you-work-or-study-ielts-speaking-20-example-answers/) also sounds strange to you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As much as the question might have some implications (i.e. it implies that someone can't work and be a student at the same time - which is not true), the answer sounds correct, according to the [definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neither) of neither.

Answer (score 1):

My 2¢:

- If you’re talking with somebody who needs the information (or whom you want to tell), such as a biographer or a prospective employer, the answer you suggested is just about right.
- For pretty much anybody else, the conventional response is, “I’m between jobs right now.”  You can elaborate if asked (but see the next bullet).
- OR, you can just find some way of saying that you find the question inappropriately intrusive.